# "Infolge Chinas Verbot" - warum nicht "Verbots"?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, genitive

1. Warum hat "Verbot" kein -s?
2. Wenn wir "Chinas" entfernen, wäre "infolge des Verbots" richtig?

Der Satz lautet:

> Die Recycling-Krise infolge Chinas Verbot könnte jedoch nach Ansicht
> der Experten auch zu besseren Lösungen für den Abfall weltweit führen.

Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nomen mit der Endung *-s* im Genitiv Singular haben die Tendenz, durch ein kongruierendes Adjektiv oder Artikelwort begleitet werden zu müssen. Der Sprachwissenschaftler Peter Gallmann, der dieses Feld seit mehr als zwei Jahrzehnten beackert, spricht von der **Genitivregel** (siehe z.B. dieses [Vorlesungsskript](http://gallmann.uni-jena.de/Wort/Wort_NP_Genitiv.pdf)). Sein Standardbeispiel ist:

> *Der Konsum Wasser**s** nimmt ständig zu.
> Der Konsum frischen Wasser**s** nimmt ständig zu.
> Der Konsum von (frischem) Wasser nimmt ständig zu.

Man beachte, daß es sich dabei nur um eine Tendenz handelt. Mit genitivregierenden Präpositionen findet man noch oft Beispiele mit unbegleiteten Genitiven:

> wegen Betrug**s**, trotz Kursverfall**s**, kraft Gesetz**es**, zwecks Verkauf**s**

Als Ersatz treten endungslose Formen auf:

> wegen Betrug, trotz Kursverfall, kraft Gesetz, zwecks Verkauf

Daher ist sowohl *infolge Verbot* als auch *infolge Verbots* möglich. Tritt der bestimmte Artikel hinzu, darf die Endung aber nicht fehlen: *infolge des Verbots*.

Die Tendenz zur Verwendung endungsloser Formen ist besonders stark, wenn ein als Artikel verwendeter Eigenname vorangeht, wie im Beispiel *infolge Chinas Verbot* oder hier:

> wegen Betrug**s**
> wegen Julias Betrug
> ??wegen Julias Betrug**s**

Ein Grund dafür ist mir nicht bekannt. Eine naheliegende Vermutung wäre, daß die Doppelung der Endung *-s* gemieden wird. Dazu passen vielleicht auch die folgenden, von Präskriptivisten kritisierten Ersetzungen:

> Anfang dies**en** Jahres (*anstelle*: dieses Jahres)
> Feind jed**en** Unfugs (*anstelle*: jedes Unfugs)

Ich habe zunächst einmal neutral von endungslosen Formen gesprochen. Da viele genitivregierende Präpositionen auch den Dativ erlauben, könnte man annehmen, daß es sich bei den endungslosen Formen in diesem Kontext um Dative handelt:

> wegen Chinas (neuem) Verbot

Comment: Vielen herzlichen Dank @David Vogt für Ihre sehr ausführliche Erklärung!