# zugunsten + genitiv oder zugunsten von + dativ

Tags: meaning, preposition, meaning-in-context

Warum von nach zugunsten im folgenden Satz?

> ... und die zwar seit zwei Jahrhunderten als soziale Grundlage fortbestehende Kleinfamilie
> verliert
> **zugunsten von** frei gewählten und gestalteten Bindungen an Bedeutung

Wäre zugunsten + Genitiv wie folgt nicht richtig ?

> ... zugunsten frei gewählter und gestalteter Bindungen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In manchen Verbindungen kann der Genitiv durch *von* + Dativ ersetzt werden. Je nach Kontext wird diese Ersetzung unterschiedlich bewertet. Im folgenden Beispiel würde die Ersetzung als umgangssprachlich empfunden:

> Der Hund meines Nachbarn bellt ständig.
> Der Hund von meinem Nachbarn bellt ständig.

In anderen Kontexten, z.B. wenn ein Nomen unbegleitet auftritt, wird der Genitiv dagegen als stilistisch auffällig bewertet (mit 
<sup>%</sup> markiert).<sup>1</sup>

> <sup>%</sup> Aufgrund Schneematsches kam es zu Unfällen.<sup>2</sup>

Hier ist die Ersetzung mit *von* voll akzeptabel; alternativ kann das Nomen ohne Endung stehen.

> Aufgrund von Schneematsch kam es zu Unfällen.
> Aufgrund Schneematsch kam es zu Unfällen.<sup>2</sup>

Im Ausgangsbeispiel sind beide Varianten voll akzeptabel.

<sup>1</sup> Das ist die Einschätzung des Sprachwissenschaftlers Peter Gallmann in seinen Skripten zur *Genitivregel*, http://gallmann.uni-jena.de/Wort/Wort_NP_Genitiv_Besonderheiten.pdf und http://gallmann.uni-jena.de/Wort/Wort_NP_Genitiv.pdf. Die entsprechenden Beispiele finden sich im zweiten Skript unter "Prestige-Präpositionen". Siehe auch folgende Antworten auf dieser Seite: [1](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/56073/35111) [2](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/61308/35111) [3](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/53893/35111) [4](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/62746/35111).

<sup>2</sup> Dass die Variante ohne Endung präferiert wird, findet sich im Vergleich der Treffer auf [presseportal.de](https://www.presseportal.de/) bestätigt: *Aufgrund Schneematsch(e)s* kommt nur einmal vor, *aufgrund Schneematsch* mehrfach. Auch im Vergleich von *aufgrund Glatteises* mit *aufgrund Glatteis* liegt letzteres vorne.

Comment: Wo hast du das Weglassen der Genitivendung her? Das hört sich gruslig an.

Comment: @tofro Das ist Gallmanns "Genitivregel". Siehe etwa Duden-Grammatik § 1534 oder den Abschnitt zu "Prestige-Präpositionen" im Skript [Genitivregel II: Besonderheiten](http://gallmann.uni-jena.de/Wort/Wort_NP_Genitiv_Besonderheiten.pdf).

Comment: Danke. Ich sehe allerdings in beiden Quellen keine "Erlaubnis", das so zu bilden, die nicht mindestens als "fragwürdig" markiert wären. Ich will nicht ausschließen, dass ich nur zu doof war, sie zu finden, aber als Beleg kann ich beide nicht akzeptieren. Kannst du mich mit der Nase draufstoßen?

Comment: @tofro Im Skript ist bei (29b) *wegen Todesfalls* als stilistisch auffällig markiert, *wegen Todesfall* nicht. Bei den Beispielen in (33) werden die Belege mit *-s* als "selten" klassifiziert, die ohne *-s* nicht. In der Duden-Grammatik unter § 1539 heißt es etwas vorsichtiger, dass sich mit bestimmten Präpositionen "noch oft" Formen mit *-s* finden; aber immerhin heißt es dort auch: "Sonst überwiegt Endungslosigkeit".

Comment: Danke nochmal. Zu (29b) *wegen* ist eine der Präpositionen, bei denen der Duden Dativ in bestimmten Fällen (speziell bei allein stehenden Nomen) akzeptiert - *aufgrund* definitiv nicht. (33) schließt "Prestige-Präpositionen" (*aufgrund* ist sicher eine) vollkommen aus. Daher würde ich "wegen Glatteis" akzeptieren, "aufgrund Glatteis" aber eher nicht.  Der §1539 überzeugt mich leider gar nicht.

Comment: Ich betrachte *wegen* hier sowieso als einen Sonderfall, weil man die Situation, dass man keinen unmarkierten Genitiv verwenden kann, hier nicht mit mit einer weiteren Präposition (*von*) entschärfen kann - Bei *aufgrund* kann man das sehr wohl und sollte es auch.

Comment: @tofro Das Problem ist, dass es sich um laufenden Sprachwandel handelt und daher mit Schwankungen und Fortbestehen des alten Sprachgebrauchs zu rechnen ist. So ist z.B. *aufgrund Personalmangels* viel populärer als *aufgrund Personalmangel*. Für mich ist aber *aufgrund Glatteis, Schneematsch* schon besser als *aufgrund Glatteises, Schneematsches*. Gallmann ist Schweizer, ich bin Süddeutscher, bei [Variantengrammatik](http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Aufgrund) heißt es lakonisch: "Die Variante ohne Endung ist vorwiegend in D-süd gebräuchlich".

Comment: Das ist alles richtig und auch so i.O. Bloß: Man sollte bedenken, *für wen* diese Site hier da ist - nämlich für Lernende. Und ob es so sinnvoll ist, regionale Ausnahmen (ich komme übrigens aus B-W und finde das Konstrukt trotzdem gruslig) ohne weitere Markierung als "voll akzeptabel" hinzustellen, stelle ich mal zur Diskussion. Der Nicht-Muttersprachler sollte wenigstens gewarnt werden, das dass keine Lehrbuchgrammatik ist.

Answer (score 0):

Ohne Präposition ist *zugunsten* ein Adverb, das *zwingend den Genitiv fordert*.

Mithilfe der Präposition *von* kann dieses Beispiel (wie viele andere Genitive) **umschrieben** werden. Und *von* fordert bis auf ganz wenige Ausnahmen grundsätzlich den Dativ. Beides ist richtig und vollkommen gleichwertig.

Comment: _umschrieben_ oder _umgeschrieben_?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Kommt das hier nicht auf dasselbe raus?

Comment: Ich denke, nein. Die nicht-trennbare Version von _umschreiben_ heißt so viel wie "vage beschreiben", die trennbare "etwas Geschriebenes ändern". Oder?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Die untrennbare Version bedeutet für mich (und Wiktionary unterstützt mich darin) "mit anderen Worten beschreiben" - bei mir kommt da kein "vage" vor, alternativ "paraphrasieren". Die trennbare Version "etwas Geschriebenes nochmals bearbeiten". Im Kontext hier kommt für mich beides mehr oder weniger auf dasselbe raus.